# using cryptographichash in Qt

Tags: qt, encryption

I am making a program in Qt5.2.1 and in it I am using a text file to store some data. I would like to encrypt it and decrypt it inside the program and display the text stored in the file in a QPlainTextEdit ( or any other similar widget).

I searched and came across Qcryptographichash but i have no idea how to use it. I read somewhere that it does not provide a very secure encryption but that doesn't matter ( I am not expecting hackers to try and read this file).

So, could anyone guide me in the right direction, maybe even give me some code. :D

Comment: It is a hash algorithm, not encryption. You cannot get back the original data you hash it from. Google hash vs encryption for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QCryptographic hash creates a hash from given data. That is a one-way process, so the it will not do what you want, namely encrypt the data in a form that can be retrieved via decryption.

You can read more about the [difference between encryption and hashes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms).

You need to research into possible encryption algorithms. To my knowledge, that's not something that is part of Qt.

It's a large area of on-going research; there are so many to choose from, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392387/most-common-encryption-algorithms).

Comment: how about crypto++ , that one provides encryption right?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use that?

Comment: I'd start by reading the manual, but it's not something I've used before: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Category:User_Guide